# Run the same function in parallel n times (while loop)

Tags: python, asynchronous, parallel-processing, python-asyncio

My program retrieves a data file and then runs the same function n times (in this example, 100) to process that data differently each time (with randomly generated ranges), and then maps the results of each trial to a file.

I tried with `asyncio` but I discovered I have been doing it wrong since it doesn't run the way I want it:

**I want it to run all the instances of the function `start_analysis()` in parallel (assuming that is the most efficient method).**

This is what I have so far:

```
import asyncio

async def start_analysis(trial, data):
    ranges = generate_ranges()

    res_1 = func_1(ranges)
    res_2 = func_2(ranges)
    res_3 = func_3(ranges)

    map_results(trial, res_1, res_2, res_3)

def main():
    data = retrieve_data()
    trial = 1

    while trial <= 100:
        asyncio.run(start_analysis(trial, data))
        trial += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: data = retrieve_data()
NameError: name 'retrieve_data' is not defined

Comment: @toyotaSupra it's a made-up function to show that the data is coming from somewhere, same as `generate_ranges()` , `map_results()` and `func_n()`. That's not the point though

Comment: No await in your async def function. Nothing for asyncio to do here. asyncio is not multiprocessing.

Comment: If `start_analysis` is just number-crunching (CPU-bound as opposed to I/O-bound) then a ProcessPool would probably be a better choice than asyncio.